# How can I get some outside input on my web app's robustness?

Tags: debugging

I am looking to get some outside eyes to do black-box testing on a simple webform-based experiment/game I made. [uTest](http://www.utest.com/) looks very good, but it's aimed at companies with lots of cash, whereas my app is just a small-time academic research project. I want to make sure that my app won't break easily, and that it's resistant against basic reverse engineering/manipulation. This is not a mission critical project, since there are no financial transactions or exchanges of confidential data taking place. However, I might eventually give out small prizes to people based on their scores, and I don't want cheaters to come out ahead.

Any suggestions for affordable black box testing?

Comment: By "robustness", do you mean that it handles well under load and scales? Or are you talking about its level of imperviousness to malicious input?

Comment: John: I mean the latter. I edited my question to make this clearer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [Chorizo](https://chorizo-scanner.com/). It's free for one host. It's primarily aimed at PHP apps but you can use it to test any kind of website for XSS and similar vulnerabilities. Just requires you to verify that you are the owner and then you setup a proxy and start browsing.